# String wrapping around 7 cylinders

Tags: geometry

If 7 cylinders of R=0.5 cm are tightly wrapped around with a tight  string, what will the string's length be? The figure clearly shows symmetry, any simple and quick way to get the answer?

[image]

Comment: Please provide more content for the question, it is not enought to copy mot-a-mot the text of a problem. What have you tried? Where did you get stuck in the middle?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a hint which might help you

[image]

Comment: beautifully explained :-)

Answer (score 0):

Curved lengths sum to the length of perimeter of the circle plus six diameters.

$$ 6 \left(\dfrac{2 \pi R}{6}+2 R\right)$$